# PPS smart card reader sended

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I want to know what PPS  smart card reader send to smart card and Is there anyway to capture it with PC?
and is there anyway I send PPS from PC with PC/SC?

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge you can not send PPS data to smart card directly.PPS handling is implement internally in Reader and Smart card OS.

If you want to spy the communication between reader and card, you can use [Micropross MP300 SC2](http://www.micropross.com/RandD-terminal-Contact-Spy-tool-MP300-SC2-19-p)

Comment: I think pps is something like Apdu. I mean we can send pps with scardtransmit. But I read in the standards after pps exchange card deactivate the pps exchange. If the reader didn't had automatic exchange I think we can send it directly with scardtransmit but the problem is may be we can change this parameters for card but how we can change them for reader.

Answer (score 0):

The PPS flow of control is described in ISO 7816, part 3 in the section *Protocol and parameters selection*. As vikky correctly states, it is below the level you have access to by PCSC, since it is in the firmware of the reader.

The card indicates its baudrate maxima (as represented by Fi/Di) in the ATR. Then the reader sends, what it would prefer, the card may accept or reject it (there is no gurantee, that any slower baudrate will work, since card and reader may only accept some special combinations). In the latter case the reader may try another.

**Update**: The reader is not obliged, to send PPS, in which case the (slow) default parameters persist. Also note that PPS logic must happen directly after reset of the card, after that the chosen rates are applied until the end of the session, i. e. to next next reset or power-off.

The only way to influence the process from the outside is, to change the ATR. How this can be done, is strongly depending on the card type used.

Comment: What happened if reader didn't send pps to card?they will work with default parameters?or they cannot communicate?

Answer (score 0):

PPS is something that's used by the card and the terminal equipment or reader to exchange the protocol parameters before actual communication between the two. It provides the baud rate and related info the card operates on. This information should be provided in the ATR of every card, as per the standards. You can find more info in the specifications ISO7816-3, ISO7816-4. You can send a PPS Request to the card and the card will respond back with the respective PPS Response if it supports the PPS. Your PC/SC reader will also exchange PPS info with the card before you start sending APDUs to the card. But PC/SC or Gemalto or Omnikey readers are not equipped to decode and display these card level info. They display only APDUs exchanged with the applications running on the card. Tools like Micropross MP300/MP500, Comprion Spy, UL Spy can decode the PPS. Consider the option of buying a good tool like Comprion or UL spy, Microposs can be too heavy for you to carry around.